# Can replication cause request throttling?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, database-replication, throttling

I have a following use case:

- we have single write region Azure Cosmos
- the db will be replicated to other Azure regions (e.g. 5 additional Azure regions treated as read replicas)
- we have a daily ETL job that cannot interrupt users querying the database. Because of that we're rate limiting in the application layer the requests we're making to Cosmos - e.g. we're consuming only 5k RUs/s out 10k RUs/s provisioned (to be strict we're provisioning 1k RUs/s with Auto-Scale setting). Thanks to that, while we're doing the ETL job we're consuming 50% of available RUs.

Question:

- is it possible that during replication we will hit 100% RU utilization in one of the read replicas because Cosmos will try to replicate everything as fast as possible?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on (1) whether the ETL is reading from Cosmos DB as a source or writing to Cosmos DB as a target and (2) what the aggregate workload (ETL + app) looks like.

I'll explain -

- The best way to think about RU's is its a proxy metrics for the physical system resources it takes to perform a request (CPU, memory, IOPs).
- Writes must be applied to all regions - and therefore consume RUs (CPU/memory/IOPs) in each of the replicated regions. Given an example 3-region setup consisting of West US + East US + North Europe - writing a record will result in RU consumption in West US, East US, and North Europe.
- Reads can be served out a single region independently of another region. Given an example 3-region setup consisting of West US + East US + North Europe - reading a record in West US has no impact on East US or North Europe.

As you suggested -

- Rate-limiting the ETL job is a good choice. Depending on what your ETL tool is - a few of them have easier to use client rate-limiting configuration options (e.g. notably, Azure Data Factory data flow and the spark connector for Cosmos DB's Core SQL API has a "Write throughput budget" concept) - alternatively, you can scale down the ETL job itself to ensure the ETL job is a natural bottleneck.
- Configuring autoscale maximums to have sufficient headroom for [RU/sec needed for the rate-limited ETL] + [upper bound for expected RU/sec needed for the application] is a good call as well - while also noting Cosmos DB's autoscale comes with a 10x scaling factor. (e.g. configuring a 20K RU/sec maximum on cosmos db autoscale results in automatic scaling between 2K - 20K RU/sec).
- One side note worth mentioning... depending on what the use-case is for the ETL job - if this is a classic ETL from OLTP => OLAP, it may be worthwhile to consider looking at Cosmos DB's analytical storage + Synapse Link feature set as an easier out-of-box solution.

Comment: Thank you! In our use case it's a data load, so 99% of the RUs are consumed creating documents. We're provisioning max 10k RUs (since we want to have only single physical partition at the moment). We don't want to consume more than 50% of the max RUs during the load since we still need to handle queries (we're fine with load taking more time). In our single write region we can rate limit our requests. However, our concern is that replication might take more RUs per sec (same RU in total but over shorter time period) and the queries will get throttled. Could you please elaborate on it?

Comment: Each region has it's own RU/s. If you want to limit to 5000 RU/s then measure how much it costs to insert each document you are trying to ETL then limit your ingestion to that amount. (1 doc is 10 RU/s to insert = 500 docs/second).

Comment: Thanks for the comment Mark! What I’m trying to say here is that we can apply rate limiting only to the requests we’re making. We have no control over the speed / throughput of the replication (or at least I don’t know how to do it). We’re ok with providing 10k RUs max per region. If the load of the documents over e.g. 2 hours consumes no more than 5k RUs/s creating documents, is it possible that because of the replication in the other regions we would see RU bursts consuming 10k RUs/s, thus saturating all available throughput for e.g. 1 minute?

Comment: The consistency policy is the only way to control replication speed but even then it may not do much. The service will replicate as fast as possible with the given RU you have. Each region get's its own RU/s. You don't count RU/s from the write region. Replication uses left over RU/s. It should not block writes unless you are using Strong consistency but then it won't be RU/s that's the factor but latency caused by replicating and committing in a region over large distances (PACLC).

Comment: Got it, thank you. So the answer is: yes, the replication might cause throughput saturation and in my read regions queries might get throttled because of it, correct?

Comment: @MarkBrown: "... you are trying to ETL then limit your ingestion to that amount. " --> how can you rate limit the ETL? I am using Azure Data Factory copy job to CosmosDB but I can't rate limit it. It works at full force and consumes 100% of my available RU's.
Any tips?

Comment: @BramCoding reduce the writeBatchSize and maxConcurrentConnections properties until you get a throughput that works for you. If you need more fine grained tuning at an RU level you need to use our Java SDK or Spark Connector.

Comment: @MarkBrown: thank you, I'll give this some time and play around with it. The Spark connector might be something useful indeed. Would you know an article to refer me to that can guide me in the right direction? Never used Spark connector for Azure Data Factory.

Comment: Sure, here's an article to get you started. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/sdk-java-spark-v3 PS: you don't run this in ADF. You run it from a DataBricks cluster or some other compute hosting Spark.