# How to see throttling requests caused by replication?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, throttling

I have next setup:
CosmosDB, one write region (Central US), one readonly region (West Europe). I need to upload new data nightly.

While uploading test data I see throttled requests to write region (Central US). But I could not find in Azure portal if throttling happened for readonly region as well or not.

- I tried to find such information in Insights - but it seems there is no grouping/filtering by region [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwUpN.png).
- I tried to create report in Metrics [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zq8JP.png) with no luck.

So my questions are:

1. Is it guaranteed that data replication could not cause throttling request? By reading that thread [Can replication cause request throttling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69406114/can-replication-cause-request-throttling) I assumed it is not guaranteed.
2. If replication process could consume enough RUs and cause throttling, how can I monitor it?

P.S. I tried to use all 5 consistency levels while uploading data.